# Compiling c using ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, codepad

How would I go about making a Website like codepad? Essentially I want to be able to compile C code after a user types it in and out put the success or error message. If it is successful, how would I be able to run it with certain parameters? (This is for a coding competition site)

Comment: What about simply running Clang (or, if you want to punish the user with bad error messages, CC) from a Ruby script? What have you tried?

Comment: Compiling is easy: just invoke a C compiler. The harder part is making sure you don't run malicious code in your server.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open Source Programming Language online interpreter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853617/open-source-programming-language-online-interpreter)

Answer (score 0):

You can call the C compiler from the ruby code by using the backticks.  Here is a quick and dirty example with Sinatra:

```
require 'sinatra'
# Display HTML form
get '/code' do
  '<html><form method="post"><textarea name="code"></textarea><input type="submit" /></form></html>'
end

# Compile code
post '/code' do
  exec = "gcc -x c -o tst - <<EOF\n#{params[:code]} \nEOF\n"
  `#{exec}`
end
```

When calling http://localhost:4567, a form appears where you can enter your C code.  When you press submit, the code is then compiled to the `tst` executable.

You can then use the backticks to execute `tst` with whatever parameters you want, similar to what is done for the compilation process itself.

The stdin output can be captured by storing the result of the backtick command in a variable, e.g.:

```
output = `tst`
```

stderr can be captured by redirecting to stdin, e.g.:

```
output = `tst 2>&1`
```

**NB: Please be careful** though, from a security perspective, this is very very dangerous: anyone can submit any C code, and get it to compile and execute on your server.